# What is the best way of authenticating an user in an angular application with .net web API?

Tags: angularjs, authentication, cookies

There are 2 ways for storing authenticated users details & send the same for each web API call.
  Save in Cookie.
  Save in Local Storage.

In my case, user details will be used in my Web API & I just need a few(around 4 values) details of user. So for me storing user details in browser is suitable. But, no matter if I am using Local storage or Cookie storage, end user can see userDetails (like UserID, tenantID etc. which are values in my DB). So there is a security issue.

To overcome this security issue, if I will use some angular encoding-decoding algorithm, my application will be slow. Is there any work around?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Web API 2 with Owin. It uses a token based authentication and works pretty well, here is the link for my implementation they follow best practices:

http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

You use a bearer auth token that is sent through to client and api to verify the users. You can also have stuff like refresh tokens for additional layers of security using the interceptor services in your angular app. So the benefit of this is, is that you do not need to store your usernames / hashed passwords etc. using local storage or cookies but only the auth token and this is then sent through to the API to verify the current user.